# How to select specific data in a list in android?

Tags: java, android, list

Hello how do I select a specific data in a list?

I have this list

[image: List]

for example I clicked on Kaiser (which is not in first nor last in the list)
I set this on the fragment

```
name.setText(obj.getName());
```

but the one that shows up is Mogul (which is the last on the list)
[image: Mogul]

so how do I select the name specifically? any ideas?

edit:

here's the fragment and adapter

```
public class LivestockDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private Livestock livestock;
    private View view;
    private ImageButton pencil;
    private EditText name;
    private ImageButton save;

    public static LivestockDetailFragment newInstance(Livestock livestock) {
        LivestockDetailFragment fragment = new LivestockDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(DVBoerConstants.DV_LIVESTOCK_EXTRA, livestock);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment_packages
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_livestock_detail, container, false);
        livestock = (Livestock) getArguments().getSerializable(DVBoerConstants.DV_LIVESTOCK_EXTRA);

        //initLivestockDetailsView(view);
        initializeEdit();



        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));

        name.setText(livestock.getName());

        return view;

    }



    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return LivestockDetailPageFragment.newInstance(livestock);
                case 1: return LivestockMedicalHistoryPageFragment.newInstance(livestock);
                case 2: return LivestockGalleryPageFragment.newInstance(livestock);
                default: return LivestockDetailPageFragment.newInstance(livestock);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        private String tabtitles[] = new String[]{"Details", "Medical History", "Gallery"};
        Context context;

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabtitles[position];
        }
    }







        /*RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.livestock_detail_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        LivestockDetailAdapter adapter = new LivestockDetailAdapter(getActivity(), livestock);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);*/


    private void initializeEdit(){
        pencil = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.editName);
        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        save = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.saveName);
        save.setOnClickListener(buttonList);
        pencil.setOnClickListener(buttonList);

    }

    private View.OnClickListener buttonList = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.editName:

                    save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    KeyboardUtility.openKeyboard(getActivity());
                    pencil.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case R.id.saveName:
                    pencil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    name.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    name.setFocusable(false);
                    save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    KeyboardCloseUtility.hideKeyboard(getActivity());

                    break;
            }

        }
    };




}
```

Comment: post your code how do you handle the list item click listener?

Comment: How you get obj object in fragment? Please post your adapter and fragment code

Comment: Are you getting last value i.e mogul  on every item click ?

Comment: can you share how you're populating your list??

Comment: sorry I am not allowed to post some codes


@akshay_shahane yes I am getting the last value on every item click

Comment: I think I'm allowed to post just this much

Comment: I can see no List here in your code. but still I am writing a few probable reasons in the answer

Comment: the list is not in that its in livestock

Comment: Have a look at my answer and try to relate it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

for every list, there's an index and you can get your specific item from index list. In your case you can also get the position from that list.

Comment: try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661895/viewpager-and-fragment-onclicklistener-not-working-right i think it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on your comment i guess you are not creating new object everytime .. if you are looping through array put Object generation code inside of loop. if thats not the case i cant help without looking at code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you problem, there can be two problems that I can see.:

1. you are not initializing your `obj` every time before adding it to the List.

   `Example:  List<Object> lst= new ArrayList<Object>();
             Object obj = new Object();
             obj.setParam();
             list.add();
             obj.setparam();
             list.add();`

   In this example before every `setParam()` you must do `obj = new Object();`
   Otherwise every time you will be setting same `Param` to all the `obj` and 
   that `param` will be none other than the last one. So every `list.add();` 
   will add same `object` to the `list`.
2. you added `obj` outside of a `loop` in which you are setting the parameters 
   (all the names) so it will add only the last `object` to the `list`.

   `example:Object obj =null;
              while(some condition is true){
               obj = new object();
               obj.setParam(); 
              }
             lst.add(obj);`

   In this example you might initialize `obj` every time but you are adding 
     only last `obj` to the `list`. Here you will have to put `lst.add(obj);` 
     inside the `loop`.

I hope your case is among these only.